# How can i fast load large amount of data using datatables?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm using Datatables to load data from database. My table has more than 3000 entries which i show on my frontend using datatable. But it take too much time to load data.
[image showing slow loading of data in datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmpN8.png)

Datatable intialize here:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.schools').DataTable({
                ordering: false,
                responsive: true,
                columnDefs: [
                    {responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0},
                    {responsivePriority: 2, targets: -3},
                ]
            });
        })
```

Laravel code to bring data from database:

```
public function show()
    {
        $schools = DB::table('schools')->get();
        return view('admin.school.view', compact('schools'));
    }
```

Comment: Pagination is your friend. You rarely need to show 3000 entries on a single page.

Comment: you can use server side datatable. you can check this  [package](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)  too.

Comment: any examples to find out code ?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can't read 3000 entries at the same time. Try fetching entries per 30 pieces and insert `next` and `back` buttons in order not to load the system with unnecessary data.

Comment: any example how to do this ?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast link, there are many similar examples.